# Will using multiple threads with a RandomAccessFile help performance?

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, file-io, concurrency

I am working on a (database-ish) project, where data is stored in a flat file. For reading/writing I'm using the `RandomAccessFile` class. Will I gain anything from multithreading, and giving each thread an instance each of `RandomAccessFile`, or will one thread/instance be just as fast? Is there any difference in reading/writing, as you can make instances that only do the reading, and can't write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly common question. Basically using multiple threads will not make your hard drive go any faster. Instead performing concurrent request can make it slower.

Disk subsystems, esp IDE, EIDE, SATA, are designed to read/write sequentially fastest.

Comment: Thanks, just the answer I wanted;)

Comment: If you want a faster hard drive use an SSD drive. It can be 5x - 30x faster than a spinning disk depending on what you are doing. Also they use less power.

Comment: Thats not true. Most disks support Native command queueing. See http://www.seagate.com/content/pdf/whitepaper/D2c%5Ftech%5Fpaper%5Fintc-stx%5Fsata%5Fncq.pdf

Comment: @StefanWoe: And if there's a command queue, then adding more threads can keep that pipeline full.

Comment: For more about why this accepted answer is unfortunately wrong, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239918/what-is-the-optimal-number-of-threads-for-performing-io-operations-in-java

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this? I have worked on this sort of benchmark for over ten years. Happy to be proven wrong, but you need to backup theory with realistic benchmarks.

Comment: I have benchmarked this as well. The better your Permanent Storage and OS is, the more do multiple threads help. In case of a RAID on x64 i.e. it helps a lot.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the answer depends on whether the hardware is sophisticated enough to take advantage of the pipelining.

Comment: The more heads you have, the greater the improvement from having multiple requests, I assume you checked behaviour of a single SATA drive for example, to ensure the queuing helped. ;)

Comment: @Steven, how could I have been benchmarking for ten years, but not actually tried it? It is an interesting world you must live in. ;)

Comment: Please see my new answer below. It shows that multiple threads even speed up reading a file on a laptop.

Comment: @Peter: Whether you take this personally is up to you, but the facts will not change to suit your feelings.

Answer (score 14):

I now did a benchmark with the code below (excuse me, its in cpp).
The code reads a 5 MB textfile with a number of threads passed as a command line argument.

The results clearly show that **multiple threads always speed up a program**:

**Update:** It came to my mind, that file caching will play quite a role here. So i made copies of the testdata file, rebooted and used a different file for each run. Updated results below (old ones in brackets). The conclusion remains the same.

Runtime in Seconds

Machine A (Dual Quad Core XEON running XP x64 with 4 10k SAS Drives in RAID 5)

- 1 Thread:  0.61s (0.61s)
- 2 Threads: 0.44s (0.43s)
- 4 Threads: 0.31s (0.28s) (Fastest)
- 8 Threads: 0.53s (0.63s)

Machine B (Dual Core Laptop running XP with one fragmented 2.5 Inch Drive)

- 1 Thread:  0.98s (1.01s)
- 2 Threads: 0.67s (0.61s) (Fastest)
- 4 Threads: 1.78s (0.63s)
- 8 Threads: 2.06s (0.80s)

Sourcecode (Windows):

```
// FileReadThreads.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "Windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <sys\timeb.h>
#include <io.h>    

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int threadCount = 1;
char *fileName = 0;
int fileSize = 0;
double  GetSecs(void);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

DWORD WINAPI FileReadThreadEntry(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)

{   char tx[255];

    int index = (int)lpThreadParameter;
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rt");

    int start = (fileSize / threadCount) * index;
    int end   = (fileSize / threadCount) * (index + 1);

    fseek(file, start, SEEK_SET);

    printf("THREAD %4d started: Bytes %d-%d\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), start, end);


    for(int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        if(! fgets(tx, sizeof(tx), file))
            break;
        if(ftell(file) >= end)
            break;
    }
    fclose(file);

    printf("THREAD %4d done\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    return 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Usage:  <InputFile> <threadCount>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(argc > 2)
        threadCount = atoi(argv[2]);

    fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rt");
    if(! file)
    {
        printf("Unable to open %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(file);
    fclose(file);


    printf("Starting to read file %s with %d threads\n", fileName, threadCount);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Start threads
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double start = GetSecs();

    HANDLE mWorkThread[255];        

    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        mWorkThread[i] = CreateThread(
                  NULL,
                  0,
                  FileReadThreadEntry,
                  (LPVOID) i,
                  0, 
                  NULL);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(threadCount, mWorkThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    printf("Runtime %.2f Secs\nDone\n", (GetSecs() - start) / 1000.);
    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double  GetSecs(void)

{
        struct timeb timebuffer;
        ftime(&timebuffer);
        return (double)timebuffer.millitm + 
              ((double)timebuffer.time * 1000.) - // Timezone needed for DbfGetToday
              ((double)timebuffer.timezone * 60. * 1000.);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this data.  I much prefer hard numbers to hand-waving, particularly as the latter tends to devolve into nerd-fights.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awesome work;) Sorry, I'm not a c++ guy, but I get the understanding that you're on a windows machine, right?

Comment: The specific version of Windows may have some effect on the benchmark results.  By all reports, more recent versions scale better on multicore processors due to a removal of global locks.

Comment: I added the OS in the answer. The application is 32 Bit in both cases.

Comment: Interesting that both cases are XP, which is not known for great scaling.  I wonder how they would run on Vista, Windows 2008 or Windows 7.

Comment: I dont run any newer OS natively. But i made serveral tests that clearly show that there are big differences between XP x64 and XP 32 Bit when memory is allocated from multiple threads. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070980/why-do-multiple-threads-eat-my-memory.

Answer (score 9):

By my experience from C++ development the answer is: Yes, using multiple threads can improve performance when reading files. This applies to both sequential and serial access. I proved this more than once, although i always found that the real bottlenecks are somewhere else.

The reason is, that for disk access a thread will be suspended until the disk operation has completed. But most disks today support Native Command Queueing [see (SAS)](http://www.neoseeker.com/Hardware/faqs/kb/15,71.html) or [Segate (SATA)](http://www.seagate.com/content/pdf/whitepaper/D2c_tech_paper_intc-stx_sata_ncq.pdf) (as well as do most RAID systems) and therefore do not have to handle requests in the order you make them.

Thus if you read 4 file chunks sequential, your program will have to wait for the first chunk, then you request the second one and so one. If you request the 4 chunks with 4 threads, they may be returned all at once. This kind of optimization has limits, but it works (although i have experiences only with C++ here). I measured that multiple threads can improve sequential read performance by more than 100%.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>`RandomAccessFile` is synchronised, so if you share an instance then you'll only have one thread running at one anyway.</strike> Oops, `RandomAccessFile` is not synchronised, and sharing between threads is not entirely safe. You will, as ever, need to be careful when you have multiple thread accessing the same mutable datastructure, particularly when the vagaries of operating systems are involved.

Small operations of `RandomAccessFile` are hideously slow.

For maximum performance, you are probably better off going straight for `java.nio`, although I would suggest getting something working before getting it to work fast. OTOH, keep performance in mind.

Comment: Or nio or even nio2 ( or whatever name it will receive now )

Comment: If going multithreaded I'm giveing each thread its own instance. But the IO being done will be the same anyway, right? So I tought it wouldn't matter, and maybe even slow the system down:O

Also, know about the "make it work first, then worry about performance", just came to think of it;) Thanks anyway:D

Comment: Oscar: typo. "NIO" and "NIO2" are both java.nio. The term NIO.2 was replaced with "More NIO Features", because legal wanted to do another search to use NIO.2 and it really wasn't worth it as it'll end up merged.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the JavaDoc on RandomAccessFile the class itself is not synchronized.  It appears that you can use a synchronous mode for read and write operations.  If you don't use the synchronized mode though you are going to have to manage the locks on reading and writing yourself which is far from trivial.  The same is going to be true for straight java.io when using multiple threads.

If at all possible you probably want to look at using a database since a database provides this kind of multi-threaded abstraction.  You might also look at what syslog options are available for Java or even log4j.

Comment: Locks on read-/write operations are not a problem, believe I have that covered:)

Comment: The mode is *synchronous*, not synchronized. This means the method call will not return until the data is committed to disk. It does not provide any thread safety guarantees, since between a seek() call and a read() call, another thread could call seek() to a different location.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised every answer talks about *performance*, but no one distinguishes *latency* from *throughput*, whereas both are performance characteristics. While you may gain additional throughput employing multiple threads, as [@RED SOFT ADAIR has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048593/298389), you trade off latency, especially in a case of Native Command Sequencing.

Comment: Glad someone commented this :) It's an important issue to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to memory map your flat file with NIO. In that case the OS memory manager becomes responsible for moving in-out sections of the file. You can also apply region locks for writers.