# Why do multiple threads eat my memory

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a Windows C++ application that holds a `std::hash_set` containing abount 5 Million entries each with 32 Bytes. If i create the hash_set in a separate (of many) threads it uses > 1 GB according to ProcessExplorer. I see this when i free the list. If i create it in the main thread it ueses 200 MB. This phenomenon only applies to the 32-Bit Version of my application. It does not oocur with the x64 Version. I use a dual quad core with Win XP x64. 
Its not a memory leak. Everything is freed on clear().

My guess: Windows 32.Bit is not constructed for many threads / many cores.

What is your gues?

Comment: Just conceivably, process explorer is wrong.

Comment: Each thread has an associated stack, but that couldn't account for all that memory unless you're spinning up many hundreds of threads.  Need code to make an "answer worthy" guess, but Win32 definitely does multi-threading adequately well; something else is going on here.

Comment: @neil: I also double checked that with vmmap. I know that all of these tolls are not exact - but hey are not totally wrong. Most of all: The 32Bit App runs out of memory faster when using threads.

@Kevin: I use about 20-30 threads at peak time. Most of them are terminated before calling clear().

Answer (score 6):

The data structure ultimately allocates from the heap, and it's the same heap regardless of the thread. Making heap calls from a different thread is not going to affect the amount of memory allocated. Either your tools are lying to you, or you're allocating the `hash_set` on several other threads by accident.